# How to combine data with a common heading from one sheet into another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an Excel sheet which is a template for doing a count of all equipment on a construction project (example below).

[image: example data]

In this example, there are two drawings which are linked to the same distribution board (eg. drawings 01 and 02) served by DB1. I would like to summarize the data in this table by the name of the distribution board so it only displays the total of each different kind of equipment, disregarding any empty cells, as shown below.

[image: example summary data]

Any help as to how to approach this would be highly appreciated, as I'm thoroughly stumped.

EDIT 01:

To provide more information, the table would actually look more like below, with the equipment being split up into various types, and user selectable from a database.

[image]

Currently, X amount of rows have been added for each and hidden. I guess the thrust of my question would be:

- How do I sum the totals for each unique piece of equipment relative to each distribution board but ALSO neglect 'empty rows'.

I have used this formula to calculate for a DUS360-CR on DB1 in the above image;
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$4:$E$4=B4)*B6:E6)

This returns the correct value, and is easy enough to replicate for all other rows but has its limitations in the sense that;

1. The formula doesn't have any knowledge to what type of equipment it is, and is simply reading through each row - which will return  many empty values because of the hidden rows.
2. I plan to have the summary of equipment for each DB in a separate sheet. As construction projects can have upwards of 50 levels at times, I would also like multiple copies of the template sheet. With the formula I currently have, the row titles (sensors/load controllers etc.) will have to be exactly the same as the original - meaning that even if only 1 quantity of an item is needed on level 50, that item will have to be selected on the original sheet, and subsequently searched - which is why there are hidden rows.

I'm not very familiar with VBA, but am open to trying, if required.

Comment: Just to check, have you tried summarising your data with a pivot table and grouping that way? I'm not sure if this is possible, but thought I'd ask if you'd tried it. Broadly, are you looking for a VB solution? Have you tried anything so far? It's best to reduce your question to a specific problem rather than generalities.

Comment: I'll second @neophlegm. As is, your question is too broad. Try something out and if you face specific issue, clearly state it in your question.

Comment: You're going to need to use VBA probably.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks heaps for the quick replies. I've tried to explain it further in Edit 01 as best I could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you don't mind a slightly different output, you can do this with a few edits, and a pivot table.

Remove the "equipment" row and the blank rows.  Then copy your table and go to a new area and Paste Special (right click) -> Transpose:

[image]

Then select that new table, go to Insert --> Pivot Table. Select [these options.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRqV7.jpg)

And there you go, albeit horizontal:

[image]